# Привязать скролл к модальному окну

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/nb7Yg/

При клике по кнопке открывается модальное окно с iframe с содержимым другого сайта.
Проблема в том, что если содержимое в модальном окне большое, то при прокрутке, если указатель мыши не на модальном окне находится, прокручивается сама страница, модальное окно улетает за границу окна.
А нужно, чтобы при открытом модальном окне при скролле прокручивалось только содержимое модального окна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то [можно сделать так](http://jsfiddle.net/nb7Yg/50/), данный способ убирает прокрутку контента под модальным окном:

**CSS** (добавляем к тому что было в изначальном примере)

```
.modal-lock {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    layer.show();
    $('html').addClass('modal-lock'); // Добавляем класс при открытии модалки
    modal.show().animate({
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        marginLeft: -150,
        marginTop: -100
    }, function(){
        $(this).html(modalContent);
    });
});
layer.click(function(){
    $('html').removeClass('modal-lock'); // Удаляем класс при закрытии
    modal.fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).html('');
        layer.fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Решение](http://jsfiddle.net/nujnqebk/). Добавил `overflow:hidden` при открытом окне

```
body.modal{
   overflow:hidden;
}

$(document.body).addClass("modal"); // При открытии
$(document.body).removeClass("modal"); // При закрытии
```

Comment: Возможно, тоже правильно решение, но первый ответ был более полным и удобным для тестирования и проверки.